# Layout with weights takes space even after setting visibility to gone

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a horizontal LinearLayout with 4 child LinearLayouts, each having a weight of 1. With all of the 4 children visible, the screen is nicely divided in a 25% ratio for all 4. But when I change the visibility of 1 child to **gone** (statically, in the XML), the layout still takes space (as if **invisible**) and the other 3 layouts keep on sharing 25% each; rather than 33% each.

I have ensured proper weights, with layout_height of 0dp. I also tried setting visibility to gone for all the children of the LinearLayout I want to hide.

What other things can I try ?

Comment: Can you post the xml for the layout you are trying to achieve this with. If we can see the code we can better figure out what might be causing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly mistake ! I had set the layout_width of parent LinearLayout as wrap_content. Changing it to match_parent worked :)